# Multiple Random Slopes and Multiple Random Intercepts In lme with Nested Variables

Tags: r, statistics, nlme

I need to write a model in R by using nlme library with multiple random intercepts and slopes.

What I need is:

1. Random intercept for Participants,
2. Random intercept for TargetID,
3. Random slope to see how the effect of OrderofImages varies across participants,
4. Random slope to see how the effect of OrderofImages varies across TargetID (meaning different targets)

MyModel

```
lme(Ratings ~ OrderofImages, 
    random = list(
      1|Participants, 
      1|TargetID, 
      OrderofImages|Participants, 
      OrderofImages|TargetID), 
    data = myData, 
    na.action = na.exclude)
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: So what exactly is your question here?

Comment: These look like crossed random effects, so it may be easier to use `lme4` instead.

Comment: Hi, participants rated the target images. So, yes crossed random effects. I am sorry that I was not clear. The order of the images being shown might affect the ratings among participants, and also order of the images can affect the ratings depending on the image being shown.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @Axeman: it's hard to know for sure, but it seems almost certain your grouping variables (participant and targetID) are **crossed**, that is that you have multiple targets with the same identity across participants (i.e., targetID "A" (or whatever) is the same target for participants Smith and Jones).  If so, then doing what you want with `lme` will be difficult; `lme4::lmer` is much better at crossed random effects, which would be specified as follows:

```
lme4::lmer(Ratings ~ OrderofImages  + 
      (1 + OrderofImages|Participants) + 
      (1 + OrderofImages|TargetID), 
    data = myData, 
    na.action = na.exclude)
```

- if you need 'denominator degrees of freedom' (F/t tests rather than chi-square/LRT/Z tests), try the `lmerTest` package
- these effects *might* be nested, if say targetID "A" is different for different participants: see the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed), or [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified), for a little more discussion of "nested vs. crossed"
- there is one crossed random-effect example with `lme` in Pinheiro and Bates's book (p. 163ff)

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified

Comment: I actually used nlme library because my dependent variable was not normally distributed. Can I still use lmer with non-Gaussian data?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. `lme` doesn't handle non-Gaussian responses (except via the `glmmPQL` extension, in the `MASS` package. You can use `lme4::glmer` to fit non-Gaussian (exponential family) responses, or `lme4::glmer.nb` for negative binomial responses, or the `glmmTMB` package for some other response distributions.